# How do you place a \n in a regex replacement string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to do something like:

```
string.gsub(/(whatever)/,'\n\1\n')
```

But I don't want "whatever" to be replaced with the literal "\nwhatever\n"
I want the \n to actually correspond to a new line.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `\n` is a newline and will be a newline.

Comment: The code that I supplied outputs "\nwhatever\n"  I want it to output "whatever" with new lines around it.

Comment: `\n` is a representation of newline in a string. if you got problems with render that string(depending on your OS) you may try `string.gsub(/(whatever)/,'\r\n\1\r\n')

Comment: That doesn't work.  It prints out \r\nwhatever\r\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need double quotes:

```
string.gsub(/(whatever)/,"\n\\1\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot all about escaping the `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

\n is a new line, that's what it means
depending on how you print it, it will give you a new line so

```
puts "\nwhatever\n".inspect
=> "\nwhatever\n"
```

however:

```
puts "\nwhatever\n"
=> 
=> whatever
=>
```

Unless I misunderstand the question.

If you wanted to split it into a list, do this:

```
puts "\nwhatever\n".split(?\n).inspect
=> ["", "whatever"]
```

Comment: puts '\nwhatever\n' outputs \nwhatever\n for me

Comment: @Tommy Do you see the difference between `'\nwhatever\n'`, what you wrote, and `"\nwhatever\n"`, what's in the answer?

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't happen. What about `puts "\r\nwhatever\r\n"` ?

Comment: @user2103316 Yes it should; escapes are ignored in single-quoted strings.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah indeed, I didn't even notice it. That's the problem

Comment: So how do I put a \n in there with single quotes?  I have to use single quotes otherwise the \1 doesn't work.